# How would I split this inputted string? (Java)

Tags: java, string, queue

I have been working on a program that prompts the user to enter strings, and they are assumed to only enter strings "f name" or "m name." It then lists the names of the males and females entered in separate lists. However, instead of the program listing just the names, it also lists the "f"s and "m"s in front of each name. I tried placing a split method after the user inputs the gender and name, but it doesn't work. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't seem to place it. Any help would be appreciated. :)

```
package labs.lab5;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameProcessor {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    UnboundedQueueInterface<String> males;
    males = new ArrayUnbndQueue<>(10);

    UnboundedQueueInterface<String> females;
    females = new ArrayUnbndQueue<>(10);      

    String input;

    do{ 
        System.out.print("Input a gender and name (x done to quit)>");
        input = s.nextLine(); 
        input.split(" ");


        if(input.startsWith("m"))
        {
            males.enqueue(input);
        }
        else if(input.startsWith("f"))
        {
            females.enqueue(input);
        }
        else if(input.startsWith("x done"))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    while(!input.startsWith("x done"));

    System.out.print("males: ");  
    while(!males.isEmpty())  
    {
        input = males.dequeue();
         System.out.println(input + " ");
    }

    System.out.print("females: ");
    while(!females.isEmpty())  
    {
        input = females.dequeue();
         System.out.println(input + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would split them as you already do using `input.split(" ");` but you need to assign the return value to something. String are immutable so that line essentially does nothing.

Comment: you dint assign the name after split try `String name=input.split(" ")[1];`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `males.enqueue(input);` with `males.enqueue(input.substring(2));`
Actually you need to skip first 2 symbols: 'm' (or 'f') and ' '.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for null values and trim the string, but otherwise a simple modification to your code, as follows, works.

```
do{ 
        System.out.print("Input a gender and name (x done to quit)>");
        input = s.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = input.split(" ");


        if(input.startsWith("m"))
        {
            males.enqueue(tokens[1]);
        }
        else if(input.startsWith("f"))
        {
            females.enqueue(tokens[1]);
        }
        else if(input.startsWith("x done"))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```